# How do I extend my kegerator beer line run properly?

Tags: temperature, kegerator, foam, diy

I have a built in kegerator in my kitchen, under the counter style. It is connected to a three tap handle tower and the lines are about 3 feet long. The noise from the compressor/fan is louder than I would like, and I am considering moving the unit to my basement, which sits directly under the kitchen counter. This would increase the run of my beer lines to something closer to 15 feet. The lines would drop down about 3 feet, then make a 45 degree turn and travel another 8 feet, then make a 30 degree turn and drop another 3 feet. My concern is the temperature of the beer in the lines, and the pressure I would need to serve at. What is the best way to ensure this longer beer line run works properly (i.e. beer is kept cool, and dispenses properly)?

Comment: Before you go to extreme measures... I bought a Bev-air commercial kegerator with a 3 tap tower and was very unhappy with the amount of compressor and fan noise. I called for service, and the first thing the tech did was to remove the fan guard. The noise instantly dropped to an acceptable level. I left it off and all is well. I am just very careful when moving kegs around to avoid the fan.

Comment: Thanks Jalynn, that's great info. I may try to remove the fan guard myself. Is there any further information you can share about how to do that? Feel free to contact me at jasonmo@mac.com. Thanks!

Comment: The fan guard is inside the kegerator in my unit, on the back wall near the top. It is just held in place with 4 phillips head screws. It's very easy to remove. I was planning to replace it with the wire guards I have seen on computer power supplies, but never got around to it.

Answer (score 2):

The Brewer's Association has the excellent [Draught Beer Quality Manual](http://www.draughtquality.org/) freely available [as a PDF](http://www.draughtquality.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DQM_Full_Final.pdf) (see the upper right corner of the page for the download).  It discusses what you'll need to account for: both line length/resistance/elevation change calculation for balancing serving pressure, and long-draw cooling options (forced-air or glycol).

Comment: Pay special attention to the cooling requirements.